# How to say "this early" as in "I have never been this early" in French?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, comparatifs

How do you say something like "I have never been this bad" in French? Or something like that? How do you say the "This bad" part?

Also, do you say "I have never been" as "Je n'ai jamais été"? Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I have never been this bad* would be translated like this :

> Je n'ai jamais été **aussi** mauvais.

*I have never been* is translated as "Je n'ai jamais été", as you said. *This bad* is translated there by *aussi mauvais*.

*This* in this kind of sentence is always translated as *aussi*. So, for your other sentence, *I have never been this early* would be translated as :

> Je n'ai jamais été **aussi** en avance.